# Java Stream API, merge by key

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a stream of objects `Couple<K, V>` and I want to obtain a stream of `Couple<K, List<V>>`, where every element `Couple<K, V>` with the same value of `K` are merged in an object `Couple<K, List<V>>`.

This is the class Couple

```
public class Couple<K, V> {
    K k;
    V v;

    public Couple(K, V v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    public K getK() {
        return this.k;
    }

    public V getV() {
        return this.v;
    }
}
```

I have to do this using Java stream

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us the class `Couple<K, V>`? How are the elements are stored in the class `Couple`?

Comment: In the class Couple there are two attributes of type K and V, a constructor method to initialize these two attributes and two public methods, one to get K and one to get V

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `K` properly override `hashCode` and `equals` methods to be used as a key in `Map`.
However, you would be needing another class for desired output:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
class GroupedCouples {
  K k;
  List<V> v;
}
```

Assuming you have `List<Couple>` couples. You can do something like:

```
List<GroupedCouples> groupedCouples = couples.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Couple::getK,
        Collectors.mapping(Couple::getV, Collectors.toList())
    )) // Map<K, List<V>> is built
    .entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>>
    .map(e -> new GroupedCouples(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

for more example [refer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to obtain a stream of Couple<K, <List<V>>, how can I obtain it from this?

Comment: @innocenzo updated answer, does it solve your problem?

Comment: @implosivesilence Since `V` is unbounded, you could also reuse `Couple` with `K→K,V→List<V>`. Just change the type of `groupedCouples` to `List<Couple<K, List<V>>` and `map` to `e -> new Couple<>(e.getKey(), e.getValue())`.